# How to achieve uniform gaussian profile? Beam profile has grainy/multimode pattern, EO says it's due to different emissivity of each phosphor atom

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, fiber-optics, photonics

I'm required to make a jig that measures the divergence angle of a collimated beam.
The setup is straightforward as shown below.

- The single-mode fiber optic cable, collimator & [NIR camera](https://www.edmundoptics.com/p/nir-ccd-usb-2-camera/29505/) are the only components that cannot be changed
- Using the camera's SDK, i'm using my python script to capture the beam profile's image and apply scipy curve_fit function to calculate the beam divergence
- Currently, I get the desired beam divergence angle only if spot image (grainy pattern) is taken ~40mm away from the [plano-convex len's](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LA1380-C) focal point OR if image is at focal point but severely saturated (flat-top profile)

[image: Focussing a Collimated Beam]

[image: Grainy beam profile]

My main problem/concern is:

1. I keep getting a grainy beam profile and I don't think it's reliable to check for beam divergence. I've searched online but I never come across this profile before. At first, we thought the profile is due to the uneven layer of phosphor coating that's on the CCD array. However, Edmund Optics said that "The phosphor coatings are usually very even but the emissivity of each phosphor atom would  not be same hence is it common to get a grainy image."
2. Not taking the image at the focal point is technically wrong isnt it? Since it's going against the formula Θ1=y2/f (using small angle approx. & Optical Invariant y2Θ2=y1Θ1)

Thus, what should I do to get a uniform Gaussian Profile?

Comment: What is the size of your beam? Did you try other lens to observe other beam size? Do you have a filter that cut visible wavelength?

I used a lot of CCD beam profiler with phosphor window to get in the 1550nm wavelength range and I never observed such a profile for a monomode fiber image.

Does the shiny points move when you move the beam on the camera? If not I would point out the bad quality of the phosphor window.

For the saturation, did you try to add neutral density?

Comment: @Aliceo thanks for reaching out!

Comment: Collimated beam diameter is 8.9mm (calculated using wlens = NA*f).

Yes, I used a 750mm plano convex lens. Generally after many tests w/ 500mm & 750mm lens, Beam Divergence is achieved if spot image taken ~40mm away from focal point (better Gaussian Profile at this spot).

Camera uses a Phosphor coated CCD array, not sure if it has an ND filter (not stated in spec  https://www.edmundoptics.com/p/nir-ccd-usb-2-camera/29505/ ). As explained by my supervisor, the phosphor coating converts the 1550 nm light into visible light which is captured by the sensor.

Comment: The shiny points (saturated spots) move when I move the beam. I tilted slightly the cage system holding the collimator & the lens too, the image detected by the sensor moves. Thus I rule out the problem being the camera.

I tried using an ND filter ​​https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=NENIR15A but this just caused the intensity of the whole spot to reduce, giving a few small saturated spot with a lesser gaussian profile. Divergence calculated here went haywire and I ended up having to increase the current of the laser source.

Comment: Also, if its the grain, the spots should stay fixed on the image, as they are always in the same location in relation to the CCD and its like you are just seeing an "inverted shadow". From what I remember, as the fourier transform is only valid in the focal plane, the image needs to be taken exactly at the focal distance. There is an error associated to an error in measurement position. Another proof is that for a complicated beam, the shape of the beam at the focal plane and another plane are completely different, so its hard to gauge a correction factor.

Comment: In other words, a beam divergence measurement needs to be done only at $f$ and not anywhere else. If you only see a nice spot 40mm after the focal distance this means that your beam was not collimated, but divergent and at $f$ you can measure this divergence.

Comment: For CCD camera with phosphor window I advise to put a filter to cut visible wavelength.